# Problems with variables on shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I've got some problems on my exercise. When I pass parameter through files using a number as variable input (1="$variable") I got those error messages each time I use variable 1:

`"cancella_versioni_preliminari.sh: 27: cancella_versioni_preliminari.sh: 1=Prova: not found"`

But files work fine. I also have some problems if I put a number as variable input in comand `"read"`, like that for example: (read 1).

By the way, here there are two screenshots of the files:

[image: shell]

(The exercise should open a directory passed by input (and all the directories inside that, recursively) and find all the .txt files with the word "preliminari" on the first line, and delete them. At the end the program prints on screen which directory have much files with that word.)

[image: shell2]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: refer to the Bash manual: [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assing to `$1` by normal assignment. You can use `set` to initialize positional parameters:

```
set -- one two three
```

It sets `$1` to `one`, `$2` to `two`, and `$3` to `three`.

Comment: Thanks choroba, now the program doesn't print any error!